# Silverlight Databinding one control to another

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, controls, listbox, checkbox

I'm working in Silverlight.
I've got a ListBox that's being loaded dynamically.
In the listbox, i want to put a checkbox that's tied to the listbox's "selected" property.   I can't quite figure out how this is done.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
If this were a winform thing, I would, create "OnChecked" handler for the checkbox to find the parent of the checkbox and set it to selected.  I'm working on the notion that there is a better way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight 2 does not offer support for what they call Element to Element Binding.

This feature has been added to Silverlight 3 which is currently in Beta.  Silverlight 3 is available at http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

In WPF you could do it by putting something the following on your CheckBox:

`Checked="{Binding Source=Listbox.SelectedItem, Path=Something, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}"`

But, sadly, Silverlight 2 does not support binding to other controls using `Source=`.

In other words, there is no better way at this point in time.  Code is all you've got.